# Using RxJava to pass Data from DialogFragment to Adapter (I am new to Rx world)

Tags: android, android-intent, rx-java, android-dialogfragment, rx-android

I have an Adapter which has some edit text and button and once i click on the button i instantiate Custom Dialog and enter some value, i need to return that value back to the Adapter so it will be auto entered back to the edit text. Is it possible to use RxJava.

Comment: you need share code in your question...

Comment: Why don't you just implement it as callback directly?